# Writing data and saving to a SQL Server database using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm pretty new to C#, what I want to do is have the user enter data into fields and when they hit submit it writes to a database. I'm really stuck any help would be much appreciated.

Here is what I have so far.

My markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="subscribe_Registration" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Your Earth, Your Home.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../StyleSheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <img src="../logo.jpg" height="200" />
    </header>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.aspx">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.aspx">Image Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://your-earth-yourhome.blogspot.com.au/">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="subscribe/registration.aspx">Subscribe</a></li>
            <li><a href="calendar.aspx">Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="donate.aspx">Donate</a></li>
            <li><a href="shop.aspx">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <h1>Subscribe</h1>
        <div class="div1">
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Name:
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="200" Height="20"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Age:<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" Width="200" Height="20">     </asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Sex:<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSex" runat="server" Width="200" Height="20"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="div2">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Address:<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Width="200" Height="20"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Email Address:<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="200" Height="20"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Phone Number:<br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" Width="200" Height="20"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Subscribe" Width="200" Height="30" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phSuccess" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <div id="success">
                    <p>Thank you for your registration!</p>
                </div>
            </asp:PlaceHolder>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <div class="links">
            <h3>Here are our affiliates:</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">http://www.earthhour.org</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">http://www.50waystohelp.com</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">http://www.greenpeace.org</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">http://www.wwf.org.au/</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <footer>&copy; Copyright Your Earth, Your Home. All Rights Reserved</footer>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class subscribe_Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registration.Registration reg = new Registration.Registration();
        reg.Name = txtName.Text;
        reg.Age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text);
        reg.Sex = txtSex.Text;
        reg.Address = txtAddress.Text;
        reg.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        reg.Phone = Int32.Parse(txtPhone.Text);

        phSuccess.Visible = true;
    }

    public void InsertRegistration()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Procedure", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parameterName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter parameterAge = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter parameterSex = new SqlParameter("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter parameterAddress = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParameter parameterEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        SqlParameter parameterPhone = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

        parameterName.Value = txtName;
        parameterAge.Value = txtAge;
        parameterEmail.Value = txtSex;
        parameterAddress.Value = txtAddress;
        parameterEmail.Value = txtEmail;
        parameterPhone.Value = txtPhone;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAge);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSex);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAddress);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmail);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterPhone);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Registration
{
    public class Registration
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm really stuck I'm not exactly sure where to go from here. I want to save the user data into a database. Not sure whats the best way or where to start. If you could at least point me in the right direction any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what are you stuck on.. where do you even call the code that inserts into the database.. I see the code for this Event.. `Button1_Click` do you know how to use the debugger..? if so put some breakpoints in your code and start stepping through the code and evaluating the variables etc....

Comment: i want to call the code with the **Button1_Click**. Is the best way to create a stored procedure or? I'm very new to programming atm just trying to finish an assignment. EDIT: sorry just read your whole comment, ill try using the debugger but I just need some tips on how to like save the data into a database.

Comment: Everything works properly just not sure where to go from here about saing to database

Comment: here is a hint.. you can't just write or create a method and expect it to execute on it's own.. where are you even calling the `InsertRegistration` method.. new or not to coding you need to understand even the pure basics.. so put the call in the button click method at the end and start from there..

Comment: how is it working properly when you have this declared `InsertRegistration` but do not even Invoke the method..? ask your Instructor to explain how to call methods from within another method.. this is looking your right dead in the face..

Comment: Yeah I know that, thing is I'm doing an online diploma where its very hard to actually learn anything because they dont give you much to work with. I kinda understand the basics of coding and I dont expect it to execute on its own, I've connected the database, tried scouring the internet for answer but cant seem to find much. So I thought Id add the question here and see if anyone could help. I followed a guide online and tried to customize it to suit me but It's not working out as well as I thought it would.

Comment: My instructor takes hours to reply hence why I posted on here. I really want to understand but its hard to grasp it when I'm doing an online diploma and dont have much to work with...

Comment: In addition to the comments above you also need to look at your parameter values. The way you have this coded you are trying to set the value of your parameters to the textboxes....you need to specify the text property of those textboxes.

Comment: this is not the place to post your `pity party` we are not here to do your homework.. also there are tons of free tutorials and YouTube videos online in regards to learning the pure basics of programming.. perhaps this is not the field for you in all due respect.. I have mentioned 2 times already what you are not doing.. you need to google how to call a method in C# .. best of luck to you..

Comment: If this were my code I would move that insert logic off your web page and into your Registration class. You would receive the values as parameters and the only code on your web page would be to call Registration.Insert

Comment: you declare this `Registration.Registration reg = new Registration.Registration();` and initialize it.but you are not even using it in regards to passing the `reg` members to the stored procedure parameters. if you are doing a lot of copy and pasting.. please understand the code that you are referencing as well as posting.. we are not here to tutor / teach you how to code..

Comment: Everything is in working order, I just don't know where to go from here. I've tried making a Stored Procedure but it doesn't seem to write to it? I know you guys aren't here to teach me how to code I just thought it wouldn't hurt to ask that's all.. Thanks for your help I guess I'll just keep looking on the internet for my answers. If it were me I would help someone but eh that's just me

Comment: I found some stuff online that might actually help sorry for wasting your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.Create a `Users` table in SQL for storing user data and a stored procedure to insert into this table:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure]
@Name VARCHAR(50),
@Age VARCHAR(50),
@Sex VARCHAR(50),
@Address VARCHAR(50),
@Email VARCHAR(100),
@Phone VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Users(Name,Age,Sex,[Address],Email,Phone)
    VALUES(@Name,@Age,@Sex,@Address,@Email,@Phone)
END
GO
```

**2.Change the code behind file like this:**

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reg = new Registration.Registration
        {
            Name = txtName.Text,
            Age = Int32.Parse(txtAge.Text),
            Sex = txtSex.Text,
            Address = txtAddress.Text,
            Email = txtEmail.Text,
            Phone = Int32.Parse(txtPhone.Text)
        };

        this.InsertRegistration(reg);
        phSuccess.Visible = true;
    }

    public void InsertRegistration(Registration.Registration reg)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.Procedure", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    var parameterName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    var parameterAge = new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    var parameterSex = new SqlParameter("@Sex", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    var parameterAddress = new SqlParameter("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    var parameterEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                    var parameterPhone = new SqlParameter("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);

                    parameterName.Value = reg.Sex;
                    parameterAge.Value = reg.Age;
                    parameterSex.Value = reg.Email;
                    parameterAddress.Value = reg.Address;
                    parameterEmail.Value = reg.Email;
                    parameterPhone.Value = reg.Phone;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAge);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSex);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAddress);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmail);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterPhone);

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Denys, your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Im getting an error on the code "The type or namespace name 'Registration' could not be found"

Comment: So add a correct `using` statement to your code behind file so that it knows where the Registration class resides

Comment: ahhh yes, thats what I forgot. Thanks for your help. Seemed to do the trick I have given you the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use breakpoints in your .cs code. most common mistake in this kind of program is that name of the field in database or .cs file are slightly different, b'coz of that server did not get the value for every field in your database. this gives an error.

So proper use of breakpoints and use debugger to debugg your program, so that u found at which point u got an error.